# why button hide after textview fulltext?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-linearlayout

i set all text in textview, but when

fulltext in textview

it make my button hide.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >


     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/InputUrl"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="left|top"
            android:hint="@string/settext"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/OutputScan"
                style="@style/Sizetext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </ScrollView>

      </LinearLayout>
```

i set edittext, textview, listview and button in one layout, because i want when click one button, the string set in textview or listview. but when text in

textview is full

my button is hide.

```
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"  >

   </ListView>

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@android:color/black" >

       <Button
            android:id="@+id/scanbutton"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/scanbutton" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/geturl"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/getbrowser" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/getSSl"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/GetSSL" />

   </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

this is screenshot when fulltext in textview:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp4RA.png)

Answer (score 1):

Provide 'android:weightSum' to top most LinearLayout and then provide layout_weight to every child. Such as

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="left"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="5"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="3.5">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/InputUrl"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="left|top"
        android:hint="@string/settext"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/OutputScan"
            style="@style/Sizetext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"  >

</ListView>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:layout_weight="0.5">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scanbutton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/scanbutton" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/geturl"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/getbrowser" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getSSl"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/GetSSL" />

</LinearLayout>
```